# Como contabilizar a quantidade de números primos em uma matriz?

Tags: c++

Estou inserindo números aleatórios dentro de uma `matriz[10][5]`, onde dentro da mesma eu contabilizo a quantidade apenas dos números primos.

Porém estou com dificuldade em extrair com o contador somente os números primos.

```
int divisores = 0;
int qtd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            for (int c=1; c<=matriz[i][j]; c++)
            {
                if (matriz[i][j] % c == 0)
                {
                    divisores++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (divisores == 2)
        {
            qtd++;
        }
    }

    cout << qtd << endl;
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Cara, qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Obrigado. 
Estou jogando números aleatórios dentro de uma matriz 10x5 e estou com dificuldade de extrair com um contador só os números primos.

Comment: Você não deveria definir `divisores` como 0 para cada novo valor verificado? Aliás, por que não cria uma função própria para verificar se um número é primo?

Comment: Estou com dificuldades para realizar isto. E minha intenção não é usar funções, se puderes me ajudar sem utilizar função agradeço.

Comment: Note que você precisa zerar a variável divisores antes de testar cada elemento da matriz. Isto é antes do loop: for (int c=1; c<=matriz[i][j]; c++). Seu teste if (divisores == 2) também deve estar dentro do loop da variável j e não após tal loop.

Answer (score 2):

**Antes de desenvolver qualquer algoritmo** você precisa **analisar a situação**, com isto precisamos saber primeiro seguinte:

**O que são números primos?**

> Um **número primo** é um **número natural maior do que 1**, cujos **únicos divisores positivos são 1 e ele mesmo**. **Todos os outros são chamados de números compostos**.

**O que caracteriza um número primo ?**

> Agregando o conhecimento da questão acima, o **único número primo par é o 2**, **todos os outros são ímpares**. Então com isto sabemos de uma **forma geral** que os **números primos não são todos os ímpares e por exceção o único número par 2**.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
#define LINHA 10
#define COLUNA 5

int main() {
    int matriz[LINHA][COLUNA];
    int number = 0;

    // ADICIONA NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS
    for(int l = 0; l < LINHA; l++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < COLUNA; c++) {
            matriz[l][c] = (rand() % 1000);
        }
    }

    //PERCORRE TODA A MATRIZ BIDIMENSIONAL, PROCURANDO OS NÚMEROS PRIMOS
     for(int l = 0; l < LINHA; l++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < COLUNA; c++) {
            number = matriz[l][c];

            // UTILIZANDO DIVISÃO SUCESSIVA DE 2 ATÉ O NÚMERO ENCONTRADO NA MATRIZ
            // SEGUINDO O CONCEITO DE NÚMEROS PRIMOS, ONDE:
            // 1)Um número primo é um número natural maior do que 1
            // 2) Únicos divisores positivos são 1 e ele mesmo
             for(int p = 2; p <= number; p++) {
                if(number%p == 1)
                    cout << matriz[l][c] << ": EH PRIMO E SE ENCONTRA NA LINHA: " << l << " e na COLUNA: " << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

E o **OUTPUT** será:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### **NOTA:**

> Basta apenas **corrigir** as repetições de **OUTPUT** do terminal.

Comment: Seu teste para verificar se um número é primo ( if(number == 2 || restDivision == 1)) está errado. Tome como exemplo o número 9 que será erroneamente identificado como primo. Note que com "único número primo par é o 2, todos os outros são ímpares" você não pode concluir que todos os ímpares são primos.

Comment: @anonimo obrigado pelo feedback! Está corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigindo sua verificação se o número é primo.

```
int divisores = 0;
int qtd = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        divisores = 0;
        for (int c=2; c<=matriz[i][j]/2 && divisores==0; c++) {
                if (matriz[i][j] % c == 0) {
                    divisores++;
                }
        }
        if (divisores == 0) {
            qtd++;
        }
    }
}
cout << qtd << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de agradecer a todos pelo apoio !

Segue código solucionado.

include 
include 
include

using namespace std;
define LINHA 10
define COLUNA 5

int main() {
    int matriz[LINHA][COLUNA];
    int number = 0;
    srand(time(0));

```
// ADICIONA NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS
for (int l = 0; l < LINHA; l++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < COLUNA; c++) {
        matriz[l][c] = rand() % 9 + 5;
    }
}
int qtd = 0;
//PERCORRE TODA A MATRIZ BIDIMENSIONAL, PROCURANDO OS NÚMEROS PRIMOS
for (int l = 0; l < LINHA; l++) 
{
    for (int c = 0; c < COLUNA; c++)
    {
        number = matriz[l][c];
        cout << matriz[l][c] << "   ";
    }
        // UTILIZANDO DIVISÃO SUCESSIVA DE 2 ATÉ O NÚMERO ENCONTRADO NA MATRIZ
        // SEGUINDO O CONCEITO DE NÚMEROS PRIMOS, ONDE:
        // 1)Um número primo é um número natural maior do que 1
        // 2) Únicos divisores positivos são 1 e ele mesmo
    for (int p = 2; p <= number; p++)
    {
        if (number % p == 1)
        {
            qtd++;
        }
    }
}
cout << endl;
cout << qtd << endl;

system("pause");
```

}