# Como exibir todos os números primos de N iniciando em 1 a partir de uma determinada entrada?

Tags: portugol

Este é o algoritmo que consegui desenvolver até agora em portugol:

```
  programa {
        funcao inicio() {
            inteiro n1, soma ,div,div2

            escreva("digite um numero")
            leia(n1)
            para(inteiro i=1 ;i < n1 ; i++) {
                para(inteiro p =1 ; p < i ;p ++) {
                    div= i/p
                    div2=i-(div*p)

                    se(div2 == 0) {
                        escreva(i,"\n")
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Um número natural primo tem unicamente dois divisores naturais distintos: o número um e ele mesmo. Como qualquer número é sempre divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo, um número natural n será primo se não existir nenhum divisor entre 2 e n-1. Utilize o operador % (Resto da divisão inteira).

Comment: não posso usar modulos

Comment: tenho que fazer do modo hard mas não to conseguindo fazer a verificação

Answer (score -2):

Atualmente na data de **09/05/19** um usuário fez a seguinte pergunta ["Como contabilizar a quantidade de números primos em uma matriz?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382682/como-contabilizar-a-quantidade-de-n%C3%BAmeros-primos-em-uma-matriz/382741#382741) e eu elaborei um algoritmo para o mesmo em **c++** **(o qual foi pedido na tag)** e expliquei para o mesmo algumas **regras dos números primos**, farei o mesmo com você, **então vamos lá?**

Antes de desenvolver qualquer algoritmo você precisa analisar a situação, com isto precisamos saber primeiro seguinte:

**O que são números primos?**

> Um **número primo** é um **número natural maior do que 1,** cujos **únicos divisores positivos são 1 e ele mesmo**. **Todos os outros são chamados de números compostos.**

**O que caracteriza um número primo ?**

> Agregando o conhecimento da questão acima, o **único número primo par é o 2, todos os outros são ímpares.** Então com isto sabemos de uma **forma geral** que os **números primos não são todos os ímpares e por exceção o único número par 2.**

```
programa {
    funcao inicio() {
        var n: inteiro

        escreva("digite um número")
        leia(n)

        para(inteiro i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
            se((i > 1) e (i % p == 1))
                entao
                    escreva("É NÚMERO PRIMO: ", i)
            fimse
        }  
    }
}
```